# Java - Converted Char Array to Byte Array - lengths don't match

Tags: java

I have some code which converts from a char array to a byte array (without creating any intermediate Strings and that's a requirement) and I'm ending up with some extra bytes at the end.  Here is some test code which illustrates the problem:

```
String s = "TomJSawyer";

System.out.println("Original String length = " + s.length( ));

char[] caOrig = s.toCharArray( );

System.out.println("Original Char Array Length = " + caOrig.length);

byte[] ba1 = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(CharBuffer.wrap(caOrig)).array();

System.out.println("byte array converted from char array length = " + ba1.length);

byte[] ba2 = s.toString( ).getBytes("UTF-8");

System.out.println("byte array converted from String length = " + ba2.length);
```

And here is the output running on jdk160_24 on Winodows.

```
Original String length = 10
Original Char Array Length = 10
byte array converted from char array length = 11
byte array converted from String length = 10
```

The extra byte that results from converting from a char array using the Charset is zero valued.  As the input string gets longer, the number of zero bytes appended to the end of the byte array grows.  I expect that this has something to do with encoding but it seems to be that I'm specifying UTF-8 both places so I don't know why that would be.

If anyone could explain to me what's going on or otherwise point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation for `CharsetEncoder.encode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode%28java.nio.CharBuffer%29) says:

> **Returns:**
>   A newly-allocated byte buffer containing the result of the encoding operation. The buffer's position will be zero and its limit will follow the last byte written.

You incorrectly assumed that the ByteBuffer's entire backing array was valid data.  You should only be looking at the bytes up to the ByteBuffer's [limit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#limit%28%29).  In fact, the CharsetEncoder.encode method does not guarantee that the returned ByteBuffer is even backed by an array, so you shouldn't be calling `array()` at all.

A reliable way to read the ByteBuffer would be:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(CharBuffer.wrap(caOrig));
byte[] ba1 = new byte[buffer.limit()];
buffer.get(ba1);
```

Comment: Thanks VGR.  That's the answer.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm new to the site.  Is there some way to mark this question answered?

Comment: From http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work : "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green (see screenshot below)"

Answer (score 1):

Char array size is different with byte array size in many scenarios. They are not same when I use Chinese or Japanese characters in char array. I just fixed a bug in my app which is related to this.

Here is the test snippet using Chinese character:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    char[] chars = new char[] { '中', '国' };
    System.out.println("string content: " + new String(chars));
    System.out.println("char array size: " + chars.length);
    byte[] bytes = new String(chars).getBytes("UTF-8");
    System.out.println("byte array size: " + bytes.length);
    System.out.println("converted string content: " + new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
}
```

Here is the output from console:

```
string content: 中国
char array size: 2
byte array size: 6
converted string content: 中国
```

Don't make the same mistake again as I made.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to use a `char[]`, you can use `StringBuffer`:

```
StringBuffer sb = "TomJSawyer";

String.valueOf(sb).getBytes();
```

Comment: StringBuffer sb = "TomJSawyer";

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  Unfortunately though, String.valueOf( ) creates an intermediate String which is what I'm trying to avoid.